Indoor Lotus leaves looking dry and not opening much
I grew my lotuses indoor from seeds and have them in a bowl now.  Though I see lots of leaves sprouting, some root away without opening and the couple of leaves that opened look dry.
I live in Wisconsin and have grow lights setup for the lotuses. I use purified water for the plants as well.
Any advice is much appreciated.
Sorry I couldn't figure out how to attach an image here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Photos aren't attached, but inserted directly (Ctl-V).
